# Android AlertDialog can not fit on this device

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am at the beginning of developing some application and kind of doing prove of concepet like things and I ran into problem which begins frustrating me: simple AlertDialog.

here's what I'm doing:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button addLocationBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addLocationBtn);
        addLocationBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        getApplicationContext());
alertDialogBuilder
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("OK",
                      new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                        result.setText(userInput.getText());
                        }
                      })
                    .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                      new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                        }

                AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

                alertDialog.show();

            }
        });



    }

}
```

here is what I get:

```
at [Source: java.io.StringReader@412f5d48; line: 1, column: 34]
02-12 19:44:53.008      748-748/com.cyanogenmod.trebuchet E/AppsCustomizePagedView﹕ Widget ComponentInfo{org.zooper.zwpro/org.zooper.zwlib.provider.WidgetProvider7x1} can not fit on this device (1032, 144)
02-12 19:44:53.008      748-748/com.cyanogenmod.trebuchet E/AppsCustomizePagedView﹕ Widget ComponentInfo{org.zooper.zwpro/org.zooper.zwlib.provider.WidgetProvider7x2} can not fit on this device (1032, 292)
02-12 19:44:53.048      748-748/com.cyanogenmod.trebuchet E/AppsCustomizePagedView﹕ Widget ComponentInfo{de.devmil.minimaltext/de.devmil.minimaltext.MinimalTextWidget_6_1} can not fit on this device (884, 144)
02-12 19:44:53.958  11114-11114/com.tepo.InTime E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
```

What am I doing wrong?
Android SDK API 8

Comment: Try setting a message and title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
```

### INSTEAD

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
```

## AND

```
result.setText(userInput.getText().toString());
```

### INSTEAD

```
result.setText(userInput.getText());
```

Comment: first clue made the thing! Thank you for being such prompt!

Comment: So you got the solution? Where was the problem?

Comment: it was needed to use MainActivity.this as builder parameter. Don't know exactly why, but it's rolling :)

Comment: Its rolling because you have to declare your dialog in MainActivity so you must have to pass the Context of MainActvity. And Yes If this solution is working for then you can accept my answer.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure this has anything to do with your error, but you need to @Override your onClicks for the .setPositiveButton and .setNegativeButton.

Comment: He should have that annotation, but it's not what causes the error.